# Docker pull does not work after ubuntu update

Tags: docker

After updating to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS docker pull does not work anymore. I get the following error:

```
sudo docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: EOF
```

tried:
add nameserver 8.8.8.8 and nameserver 8.8.4.4 to /etc/default/docker did not help

Thanks a lot!

Docker version 17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6

```
curl -v 'https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/'
* Trying 130.75.6.113...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to secure-proxy.bla.de (130.87.6.113) port 3131 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to registry-1.docker.io:443
> CONNECT registry-1.docker.io:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: registry-1.docker.io:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Tue, 26 Jun 2018 08:00:51 GMT
< Server: C-ICAP
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Language: en
< X-Cache: MISS from secure-proxy
< X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from secure-proxy:3131
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
* CONNECT responded chunked
< Via: 1.1 secure-proxy (squid/3.5.19)
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
* CONNECT phase completed!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Comment: We'll need more info to understand what's wrong. When faced with a problem like this, I'd start by trying to understand what's coming back from the URL and whether it is a connection problem or a docker problem. For example, what happens when you try this? `curl -v 'https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/'`

Comment: I added it @mkasberg

Comment: Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind an HTTP or HTTPS proxy server you need to add this configuration in the Docker systemd service file. It works after doing what is described here
https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy